# Find document in subarray in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have many collections such this

```
{
"_id" : 383566,
"horses" : {
    "609075" : {
        "_id" : 609075,
        "name" : "Aghawonan"
    },
    "634478" : {
        "_id" : 634478,
        "name" : "French Thyne"
    },
    "595535" : {
        "_id" : 595535,
        "name" : "Doctor Hanley"
    },
    "593718" : {
        "_id" : 593718,
        "name" : "Ballyhill Boy"
    },
    "578089" : {
        "_id" : 578089,
        "name" : "Oh Alabama"
    },
    "632597" : {
        "_id" : 632597,
        "name" : "Bowling Alone"
    },
    "525424" : {
        "_id" : 525424,
        "name" : "Tally-Ho Duke"
    }
}
```

I need to find all the collections in the array where Horses _id have match

My version, but it does not work

```
db.cards.find({'horses': {$elemMatch: {_id:525424}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example, `horses` is not an array, but an object. This data structure is a bit odd and redundant because the id is both part of the 'name' (or path if you will) and the actual document data. In your data structure, you could refer to a particular horse by `horses.609075.name`, but that is usually not very helpful.

Your query would work if `horses` were an array like so:

```
{
  "_id" : 383566,
  "horses" : [
    {
        "_id" : 609075,
        "name" : "Aghawonan"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 634478,
        "name" : "French Thyne"
    },
    // ...
   ]
 }
```

Since you're only querying for a single property, the `$elemMatch` isn't required. You could simply query like this:

```
db.cards.find({"horses._id" : 609075});
```

Please note that you'll receive the entire card as a result, not just a part of the array.

As a *side note*, why are the ids of the horses called `_id`? The name `_id` is a special field only at the root level. Embedded documents don't have any special fields.

Comment: Sorry, horses - Object

Comment: That comment doesn't seem to make any sense? If you're bound to model `horses` as an object, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I already knew it possible to somehow change the field type Horses with an array object to 139,000 records

Comment: `db.cards.find({"horses._id" : 609075});` - not working

Comment: Of course not, unless you change your model to an array as I pointed out in my answer. You should review the terms used in MongoDB (collections, array and documents) and change your data structure.

Comment: Yes, it is of course my big mistake. Is there any way to change the type of field horses in an array?

Comment: Not really, you'll have to write a program that fetches all documents and writes new ones with arrays instead of objects.